# App binding still causes class not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

So I have this app binding in `routes.php`:

```
App::bind('HybridAuth', function()
{
    return new Hybrid_Auth(Config::get('hybridauth'));
});
```

and this constructor on my controller:

```
public function __construct(UserRepository $user, HybridAuth $oauth)
{
    $this->user = $user;
    $this->oauth = $oauth;
}
```

Why am I still getting a `Class HybridAuth not found` error in the controller? Shouldn't it use the app binding that I just did.

Comment: That's because binding doesn't create an alias to the class, but rather an instance of it. If you want an alias, go on app/config/app.php and add it under alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that's mainly because when you do the binding, you're not really creating an alias to the class, but rather to a instance of that class, which could later be accessed doing `App::make('HybridAuth')`.

If what you want is to create an alias to the class itself, as it seems to be the case, go on  `app/config/app.php` and add it under `aliases` key. Something like this:

**app/config/app.php**

```
'aliases' => array(
    'HybridAuth'      => 'Hybrid_Auth',
    // ...
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about how that oAuth class is loaded (or not auto loaded), my guess is that you *may* need to tell Laravel where your `Hybrid_Auth` class is. Note that binding like that (with Laravel's sprinkle of magic in the controller) is not a substitute for setting up autoloading - PHP still needs to know how to find your classes.

```
App::bind('HybridAuth', function()
{
    return new Hybrid_Auth(Config::get('hybridauth'));
});
```

May need to become something more like this:

```
App::bind('HybridAuth', function()
{
    return new \Some\Namespace\Hybrid_Auth(Config::get('hybridauth'));
});
```